# My CSS is not working properly in vs code

Tags: css, reactjs

I have written a simple navbar that has a scroll animation.
Example:

```
<div className={"nav active"}>
```

Here CSS on `active` is not working. Even if I write `.active` or `nav.active` in my CSS file, I have no result. In my code I have used a `on scroll` event listener so when I scroll down, the navbar appears black and when I go on the navbar, it disappears. But the problem is that CSS is working in `nav`, but not working in
`active` and as a result black color in `active` is not appearing.

```
    const  [show , handleshow]= useState(false);

    const transitionNavBar = () => {
        if (window.scroll > 100){
            handleshow(true);
        }else{
            handleshow(false);
        }
    };
     useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll",transitionNavBar);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", transitionNavBar);
     }, []);
    return (
        <div className={`nav ${show && "active"}`}>
            <div className="nav_contents">
            <img className='nav_logo'
        src="http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c529.png" 
      alt=""
        />
        <img className='nav_avatar' src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0d/dc/ca/0ddccae723d85a703b798a5e682c23c1.png"
         alt=""
         />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}



.nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}

    .nav.active{
        background-color: #111;
    }
    
    
    .nav_contents{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .nav_logo{
        position: fixed;
        top: 10px;
        left: 0%;
        width: 80px;
        object-fit: contain;
        padding-left: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .nav_avatar{
        position: fixed;
        cursor: pointer;
        right: 20px;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
```

Comment: `<div className={\`nav ${show && "active"}\`}>` wouldn't this give your element the classes nav and then either true or false ? try something like `<div className={\`nav ${show ? "active" : "" }\`}>`

Comment: but css is not even working if wipe up everything and just try to add css in active <div className={"nav active"}>. here css works perfect in "nav" but it doesn't in "active".

Comment: thankyou for replaying i dont know what was a problem but when i uninstall and install vs code again it worked i dont know how but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

`` <div className={`nav ${show && "active"}`}> ``

Try this:

`` <div className={`nav ${show ? "active":""}`}> ``

Comment: i tried this too but that active is not detecting css just nav is only detecting css.

Comment: In dev-tools, can you see if the class is applied in the html? Or is it not even visible in the html?

Comment: i tried to view in inspect of google but its not even there yeah its not even visible.

Comment: Not even there when you write it without the conditional statement (`className="nav active"`)?

Comment: not detecting css in active . and i am getting frustrated because i was doing all the same thing which were shown in video but it didn't work on me . so i started another way to use on scroll animation. but all were same u need that second element in className and my vs code it didn't work. so thats the problem i have tried it all and at the end i am asking.

Comment: thankyou for replaying i dont know what was a problem but when i uninstall and install vs code again it worked i dont know how but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write your CSS in a seperate file, if you are not using [styled components](https://styled-components.com/) for example.
Write your CSS classes inside a seperate file and then import the css file inside your JSX/JS.

For example:

```
import "./navbar.css"
```

Edit: Sorry, just reread and noticed your nav is working.
As the other posts suggest, you would probably need to use a conditional operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: it is in separate file its just i am posting question for first time and errors were coming so i wiped all import statements and add all code directly the real problem is . css is not even working if wipe up everything and just try to add css in active <div className={"nav active"}>. here css works perfect in "nav" but it doesn't in "active".

Comment: thankyou for replaying i dont know what was a problem but when i uninstall and install vs code again it worked i dont know how but it worked.

Comment: Gotcha. If it still isn't working, maybe post the code in a codesandbox.
Edit: Ah, perfect  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was a problem but i uninstall ns install vs code again my issue was solved I really don't know how it worked but it worked.